# windows VC9 ffmpeg and magick wand

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg, magickwand

I am looking for a ffmpeg and magickwand extension for PHP 5.3 compiled with MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008).

Anyone know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me using Xampp Win32 on Windows XP with PHP v5.3.8 VC9

http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=430